# Show a $W^{1,p}$-solution is a weak solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm a little bit confused about the idea of being a $W^{1,p}$ solution of an equation. The example I'm looking at is the following: Let $J:\mathbb R^{2n}\to GL(2n,\mathbb R)$ be a $C^1$-function with $J^2=-1$. Suppose the function $u:B_\epsilon\to\mathbb R^{2n}$ is "$J$-holomorphic" in the sense that $$\tag{$*$}\partial_su+J(u)\partial_t(u)=0.$$ (Here $\mathbb C$ is given coordinates $z=s+it$ and $B_\epsilon\subset\mathbb C$ is the ball of radius $\epsilon$.)

I'd like to show that a $W^{1,p}$-solution $u$ of $(*)$ with $p>2$ is also a weak solution of
$$\Delta u=(\partial_tJ(u))\partial_su-(\partial_sJ(u))\partial_tu.$$

I'm having trouble seeing this. I'm not even sure what it means to be a $W^{1,p}$-solution or a weak solution if $u$ doesn't have codomain in $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denote the eculidean standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. If $u \in W^{1,p}(B,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ is a weak solution to
$$
\partial_s u+J(u)\partial_tu=0,
$$
it means that
$$
\int_B \langle \partial_s u+J(u)\partial_tu, \psi \rangle dsdt=0
$$
for every choice of $\psi \in L^p(B,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$. Some textbooks require the test function to be in $C_c^{\infty}(B,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$, but by density, this extends to $L^p(B,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$. The reason I am doing this, is because $J$ is only $C^1$, but not necessarily $C^{\infty}$. This way,
$$
\psi=\partial_s \phi -J(u)^T\partial_t \phi \in L^p(B,\mathbb{R}^{2n}),
$$
for $\phi \in W^{1,p}(B,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$, is an admissible test function, since every function $W^{1,p}(B,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ for $p>2$ is Hölder continouos and therefore the term $J(u)$ remains bounded on $B$. Expanding yields
\begin{align*}
0&=\int_B \langle \partial_su,\partial_s \phi\rangle+\langle J(u)\partial_t u,-J(u)^T\partial_t \phi \rangle  + \langle \partial_s u, -J(u)^T\partial_t  \phi \rangle + \langle J(u) \partial_t u, \partial_s  \phi \rangle dsdt \\
&=\int_B \langle \partial_su,\partial_s  \phi  \rangle+\langle \partial_tu,\partial_t \phi \rangle-\langle J(u) \partial_s u, \partial_t  \phi \rangle +   \langle J(u) \partial_t u, \partial_s  \phi \rangle dsdt.
\end{align*}
Here we have used that $J^2=-1$. But this is precisely the weak version of
$$
\Delta u=(\partial_tJ(u))\partial_su-(\partial_sJ(u))\partial_tu.
$$
Lets see why: If we assume that $u$ is a smooth solution, then we note that
$$
\partial_t(J(u)\partial_s u)-\partial_s(J(u)\partial_t u)=(\partial_tJ(u))\partial_su-(\partial_sJ(u))\partial_tu
$$
by the product rule and Schwarz lemma. Take now any test function $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(B,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ and $u$ a smooth solution of the above equation. Then we have
\begin{align*}
0&=\int_B \langle (-\Delta u+\partial_t(J(u)\partial_s u)-\partial_s(J(u)\partial_t u), \phi \rangle dsdt \\
&=\int_B \langle \partial_s u, \partial_s \phi \rangle + \langle \partial_t u, \partial_t \phi \rangle  -\langle J(u) \partial_s u, \partial_t  \phi \rangle +   \langle J(u) \partial_t u, \partial_s  \phi \rangle dsdt,
\end{align*}
where we have integrated by parts in every term. We could now demand the above equality to hold for every $\phi \in W^{1,p}(B, \mathbb{R}^{2n})$, and then you got the weak formulation.